# Selecting checkboxes using a script on a third party website

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to use jQuery to create a script that will select specific checkboxes on this page. I can't seem to figure out how to select specific ones, it seems not matter what I've tried it's not selecting the correct one from the list. Looking at the code, they use checkRole(#) for 80 something checkboxes. What can I do to modify this code to select, for example, the 3rd, 10th, and 20th checkbox?

Here's my code:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
$("#detail input:checkbox").click();
```

And heres a link to the offline html of the site I'm trying to do this one:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3keruc1t2w7bcon/code.7z?dl=0

It's a 3rd party site and I'm not able to modify their code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each checkbox has a unique value. Assuming this is the case and you know the value of the checkboxes you want to check, you can use something like this for each:

```
 $('tr input[type=checkbox][value=200]').prop('checked', true);
```

Change the value to whatever it is for the box you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.click();` and `#detail input:checkbox` you should use one of the following:

jQuery ( >= 1.6):

```
// Check
$("input[type=checkbox][id=detail]").prop("checked", true);

//  Uncheck
$("input[type=checkbox][id=detail]").prop("checked", false);
```

jQuery ( <= 1.5):

```
// Check
$("input[type=checkbox][id=detail]").attr("checked", true);

//  Uncheck
$("input[type=checkbox][id=detail]").attr("checked", false);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kc4z5ve6/1/